# How to understand differential forms easily?

Tags: differential-forms

How to understand differential forms in connection with topological/differential manifolds, especially, how does differential form connect with homology, cohomology etc.

I used the word "connect" in the usual sense, not in a mathematical sense. It will be great if I get to differential forms in any manner from the ideas of homology, cohomology etc.

Comment: You can’t understand the DeRham isomorphism theorem with any depth without first learning differential forms and Stokes’s Theorem.

Comment: You may like [this book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm:978-3-319-96992-3/1.pdf).

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you. It presents the concepts nicely and I could pass through it in a flow.